# How to add custom animations viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, viewflipper

How to add custom animations viewpager, or how to manually slide viewflipper. Need follow the movement of the finger, thanks.

Comment: Have you try this http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check please http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html for this purpose. This article describes a `ViewPager` that has a default animation that you need.

Comment: thank you, I found, Customize the Animation with PageTransformer

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a custom view from ViewPager and then override the onTouchEvent method. There in ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP, you can write your logic.